# How to bind text as different and value as different from DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to bind text as different and value as different from DataTable in CheckBoxlist

In my DataTable I have two columns

```
   UserName              UserID

   AAAAA                 12
   BBBBB                 13
```

I binded this datatable in Checkboxlist

```
  this.CheckList.DataSource = dataTable;
  this.CheckList.DataBind();
```

What's the problem is? after binding text as UserName and value also Username

but here I want to bind value as UserID.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to set datavaluefield and datatextfield before binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties:

```
this.CheckList.DataSource = dataTable;
this.CheckList.DataValueField = "UserID";
this.CheckList.DataTextField = "UserName";
this.CheckList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` of `Checkboxlist` control.

```
this.CheckList.DataValueField = "UserID";
this.CheckList.DataTextField = "UserName";
```

Find more details [here](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-bind-data-to-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1042.aspx).